# Changing a setting variable from settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am using Django 1.3 with mod_wsgi

In my `settings.py`

```
DISABLE_SYSTEM = False
DISABLE_USER_INTERFACE = False
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
]
if DISABLE_SYSTEM:
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.insert(0, 'SomeMiddleware')
if DISABLE_USER_INTERFACE:
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.append('SomeOtherMiddleware')
```

When i set `DISABLE_SYSTEM` to `True`, `SomeMiddleware`'s `process_request` function returns a warning message with `HttpResponse` and following Middewares do not run at all.  That gives me a kind of *System shutdown for maintenance*

`DISABLE_USER_INTERFACE` filters `request` and any view function called by a user is blocked, while `admin` urls and management functions runs normally.

Up to now, i used this for maintenance of different kinds, and i simply change it from the file and *touch wsgi* to re-reload python modules. But now, i need to use a kind of scheduled routine to stop *user based requests* and do some maintanance on the background and some from admin.

At this point, i system (but not user) needs to set `DISABLE_USER_INTERFACE` to `True` from `settings.py` and start maintenance. But i could not find  porper way to do it or a better way to handle this not from `settings.py` but somewhere else.

Lines in `settings py` than changes `DISABLE_USER_INTERFACE` is because i need to use this function once per day and using these two middleware for each request do not seem logical to me. So in my current model, they run only when they are needed to be run

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** What i want to do is disabling user interface during 19:00 - 19:30 everyday. I am not sure about making a middleware level check like:

```
if 19:00<now()<19:30:
    stop system
```

for every request. I need something more efficient that avoids unnecessary process. Or is middleware the right choice for that kind of works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have scheduled changes to your settings, you might want to reconsider what you're doing.

Your Middleware can be much, much smarter.  This makes it possible for your settings to be much, much dumber.

I would strongly suggest that you have one `SomeMiddleware` class which is **always** installed.

That `SomeMiddleware` class can then check the `settings` and decide which behavior it should perform.

There are still better ways to do this.

You don't necessarily need to revise the settings for the scheduled maintenance.  You have lots and lots of ways of communicating with your middleware in a running Django application.  One of the fastest is through the database.

You have can an "operating mode" class definition with one (or a few) attributes which are simply fetched by the middleware to see what's going on.  You can write your admin apps to do a simple Update on this table to change the mode.

You can have an "operating mode" file names which (if present) change the middleware's behavior.  You need only do `os.path.exists()` kind functions to check (quickly) what to do.

Comment: What i want is to close the system between 19.00 to 19.30, i thought about writing a middleware which checks time for each request and blocks them if it is maintenance time, but running a `if 19.00<now()<19.30: stop system` control for each request seemed unnecessary. I am looking for something more efficient...

Comment: "but running a if 19.00<now()<19.30: stop system control for each request seemed unnecessary". Actually, the overhead is unmeasurably small.  However, that's why I suggested of creating a file in a known location.  cron can create and remove this file on your schedule.

Comment: Thanks, since i am using `memcached` module,i set a cron to create a cache key and my MiddleWare checks for existance of that key. Since `memcache` supports `lifetime` for each `memcache` object, there is no need for a second cron to remove related cache key.

Comment: "my MiddleWare checks for existance of that key."  It's probably much less expensive to check the time.  However, since you're happy with this, cheers.

Comment: Thanks, i will make some stress test to check the diffrence between two (: